# What Columns Should I Index to Improve Performance in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In my query I have a temp table of keys that will be joined to multiple tables later on.

I want to create an index on my temp table to improve performance, cause it takes a couple of minutes for my query to run.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    k.Id, k.Name, a.Address, a.City, a.State, a.Zip, p.Phone, p.Fax, ...
FROM
    #tempKeys k
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Address a ON a.AddrId = k.AddrId
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.Phone p ON p.PhoneId = a.PhoneId
...
```

My question is should I create an index for each column that is being joined to a table separately

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... (Addr.Id ASC)
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... (PhoneId ASC)
```

or can I create one index that includes all columns being joined

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX ... (Addr.Id ASC, PhoneId ASC)
```

Also, are there other ways I can improve performance on this scenario?

Comment: What index will help depends on the query being used to select data from the table. You need to show us. But its a big topic, you'd be much better off studying more about indexes than having us give you the answer since it won't help you much next time you come to add an index.

Comment: Are you filtering on your temp table in that query? It looks like it's really being used to drive some joins to other tables. If the temp table is a subset of the values in the tables you're joining to then you probably don't want any indexes on it.

Comment: I would also want to know if the joining tables are large tables. Sometimes you need to prefilter what you need from individual tables into temp tables so you have less records to process. Also the fact your suggesting the index for both columns on your temp tables shows you do not understand them enough. Also, as others have pointed out, we do not see the whole query. We cannot even begin to give you insights on indexing without seeing the whole query.

Comment: It almost sounds like AddrId and PhoneId are already primary keys. If there not...then by all means yes...create them individually.

Answer (score 1):

As @DaleK says this is a complex topic.  In general though, an index is only usable when all the leading values are used.  Your suggestion of a composite index will likely not work. The indexed value of PhoneId cannot be used independently from AddrId. (The index would be ok for AddrId on its own)

The best approach is to have a test database with representative data & volumes then check the query plan & suggestions.  Don't forget every index you add has a side effect on the insert.

Another factor is that without a WHERE clause or if there are larger data sets (I think over 5-10% of the table), the optimiser will decide it's often faster to not use indexes anyway.

And I'd rethink using temp tables anyway, let alone indexed ones.  They're rarely necessary.  A single, large query usually runs faster (and has better data integrity depending on your isolation model) than one split into chunks.